# Why does WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext need a private field named controlToSendTo?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have read the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/94ce4a2e52bf5d0d07d3d067297d60c8a17dc6b4/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs) of `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`.

The whole Winform basically runs on a thread which is called 'UI Thread'.That's the reason why another thread must back to the specific thread when it is done. And `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` basically sends the message(Action) to the queue and waits for it to be invoked.
So, what's the difference between label1 sending a message or button1? Is `private Control controlToSendTo` necessary in this class?

```
//below methods have the same effect
button1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = "hello"));
label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = "hello"));
```

Comment: There could be multipe "UI threads".

Comment: _"The whole Winform basicly run on a thread which called 'UI Thread'"_ - you'll find that is the case with most GUI toolkits and is not specific to .NET let alone WinForms. They are all single-threaded.

Comment: By the way consider using `.BeginInvoke` instead of `.Invoke` because the latter can lead to thread _dead-lock_.  This allows for asynchonous processing of the Windows Message Pump

Comment: When you call `Invoke()`, what happens first is that [FindMarshalingControl()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,6279) is called, to find an UI element that has a Handle, starting from the Parent of the Control that invoked. If no Controls with a Handle is found, the Control that invoked is the marshaller, counting on the fact that `MarshaledInvoke()` will throw after. If it's a valid handle, `MarshaledInvoke()` captures the SysnchronizationContext from the current Thread.

Comment: Then it [Waits](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,7841) for a callback to return if you called `Invoke()`, or calls `PostMessage()` if you called `BeginInvoke()`. That's one of the reasons why you prefer to use `this.Invoke()` or `this.BeginInvoke()` instead of using a child Control as marshaller. -- In any case, the marshaller is already identified before any action is taken; what the `SynchronizationContext` is doing internally, here, is not relevant.

Comment: @Jimi it's very kind of you! And can you suggest me a book or blog to learn more about winform?

Comment: You can check the more recent publications of Charles Petzold / Chris Sells for WinForms, Mark Russinovich / Pavel Yosifovich for the *Internals* and of course study the [.Net Framework Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) and [.Net 5 WinForms source Code](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms), [.NET Desktop Guide for Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/?view=netdesktop-5.0) and the [.Net Foundation documentation](https://dotnetfoundation.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Winforms is odd, in that you can have multiple UI threads, but each `Control` is associated with a single UI thread. This means that it's possible for one control to be associated with one thread, but a different control is associated with a different thread.

The way to post a message to a given UI thread is to find a control associated with that thread, and call its `Invoke` method.

When a [new `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` is created](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,d37865bac8deb498), it [creates](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,150fc91c7f8e7176) a new [`MarshalingControl`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,5c57f54c826c702b), which is a dummy `Control` associated with the current thread. When you [Post](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,de633159d3cb47c3,references) to that SynchronizationContext, it [invokes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,96) that `MarshalingControl` that it created previously, in order to post to the thread that it previously associated with that control.

Comment: 1.Is that means how many UI threads it has and it has the same quantity of MarshalingControl?   2.Why it can have multiple UI threads,or can u prove it?  Thanks a lot~

Comment: I don't understand the question I'm afraid. "Is that means how many UI threads it has" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Vincent - it's easy enough to demonstrate it to yourself. In a normal windows forms application, on a button press create a second thread and do `Application.Run` on that thread - simplest would be to use the overload that takes another form - you'll find the new thread is "the" UI thread for that form. Basically, UI threads (in WinForms terms) are the threads that call `Application.Run` and end up running message loops inside that call.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is 'multiple UI threads' means every Application.Run invoked creates a new single UI Thread? The new dummy MarshlingControl is build in order to find which one is control's thread?  And is WPF have the same multiple ui threads situacion? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Vincent - no, each Application.Run is invoked by *some* thread. At that point, *that thread* becomes a UI thread (until the message loop it's running is told to shut down, at which point that `Run` call finally returns). I'd imagine the same can be done in WPF. This is a *Windows* thing, not a WinForms/WPF/other tech thing. I couldn't say whether the same can also occur in other windowing systems.